# Como colocar um comando de SQL em uma variável

Tags: sql, sql-server, variáveis, sql-server-2012

Tenho um seguinte comando em SQL e preciso coloca-lo dentro de uma variável em SQL. O código é esse.

```
 WITH DB_CPU_Stats
        AS
        (SELECT SUM(total_worker_time) AS [CPU_Time_Ms]
        FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats 
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT CONVERT(int, value) AS [DatabaseID] 
                  FROM sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(plan_handle)
                  WHERE attribute = N'dbid') AS F_DB
        GROUP BY DatabaseID)
        SELECT CAST([CPU_Time_Ms] * 1.0 / SUM([CPU_Time_Ms]) OVER() * 100.0 AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS [CPU Percent]
        FROM DB_CPU_Stats
        ORDER BY [CPU Percent] DESC;
```

Qual seria uma forma fácil e prática de fazer isso. Já tentei de várias maneiras porém não consegui fazer o mesmo.

Esse script é para um aplicação que eu estou desenvolvendo que no momento eu preciso pegar a porcentagem de processamento da CPU através desse script em SQL.

EDIT: Linguagem: Transact-SQL, Banco de dados: SQL Server 2012

Comment: Você quer criar uma variável em SQL ou uma variável no seu *script*? Em que linguagem é o *script*? E qual o banco de dados (para saber qual variação do SQL está usando)?

Comment: Qual o banco de dados amigo? Clique em [edit] e insira nas tags.

Comment: Quero criar uma variável no script. Transact-SQL. SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Variável em sql ? c tá fazendo uma stored procedure ou trigger ? se não estiver não faz sentido variáveis em sql. sql é uma linguagem de queries, não uma linguagem de programação. Destina-se a extrair dados do banco. Vc elabora a consulta, aí no seu programa (php, c++, java, etc) vc a coloca em uma variável string e a envia ao banco e aí o banco retorna os resultados e vc captura os resultados em alguma variável. Não faz sentido portanto existir variável na consulta. A menos que esteja se referindo a parâmetros como "and data = :minhaData" pra vc poder usar a mesma consulta pra várias datas.

Comment: Estou fazendo uma stored procedure

Comment: Mas não era um *script*? Agora virou Sproc?

Answer (score 1):

Assim:

```
    DECLARE @COMANDOSQL VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @COMANDOSQL = 'WITH DB_CPU_Stats
            AS
            (SELECT SUM(total_worker_time) AS [CPU_Time_Ms]
            FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats 
            CROSS APPLY (SELECT CONVERT(int, value) AS [DatabaseID] 
                      FROM sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(plan_handle)
                      WHERE attribute = N''dbid'') AS F_DB
            GROUP BY DatabaseID)
            SELECT CAST([CPU_Time_Ms] * 1.0 / SUM([CPU_Time_Ms]) OVER() * 100.0 AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS [CPU Percent]
            FROM DB_CPU_Stats
            ORDER BY [CPU Percent] DESC;'

--Imprime conteúdo do comando
PRINT @COMANDOSQL
```

Comment: A ideia é esta só que existe um pequeno erro, deve trocar: `'dbid'` por `N''dbid''`, para poder retornar aspas simples dentro das aspas simples da variável `@COMANDOSQL`.